# "Missing region in config" after attempting to mock SecretsManager with Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, aws-sdk

I'm currently attempting to mock AWS SecretsManager for my unit testing with Jest, and everytime I'm hit with the `ConfigError`
My code is somewhat like this

```
//index.ts
import SM from "aws-sdk/clients/secretsmanager"
const secretManagerClient = new SM()
...
export const randomMethod = async (a: string, b: string) => {
  let secret
  const personalToken = {
    SecretId: process.env.secretId,
  }
  secretManagerClient
    .getSecretValue(personalToken, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(`[SECRETS MANAGER] Error fetching personal token : ${err}`)
      } else if (data && data.SecretString) {
        secret = data.SecretString
      }
    })
}
```

My mock goes like this :

```js
//index.test.js
const mockGetSecretValue = jest.fn((SecretId) => {
  switch (SecretId) {
    case process.env.GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN:
      return {
        SecretString: process.env.GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN_VALUE,
      }
    default:
      throw Error("secret not found")
  }
})

jest.mock("aws-sdk/clients/secretsmanager", () => {
  return jest.fn(() => {
    return {
      getSecretValue: jest.fn(({ SecretId }) => {
        return mockGetSecretValue(SecretId)
      }),
      promise: jest.fn(),
    }
  })
})
```

However, I get this error thrown at me : `ConfigError: Missing region in config`, which I understand to some extent, however I don't understand why it occurs here in the mocking part...

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Thanks to the 1st answer, I've managed to stop having this error. However, the `getSecretValue()` method is not returning the Secret value I want.

Comment: What does `secretManagerClient` come from? How did you initialize it?

Comment: `secretManagerClient` is initialized outside of the method, at the top of the file.
I've edited the code to show that.

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT use the callback of `.getSecretValue()` method with `.promise()` together. Just choose one of them. The error means you didn't mock the `secretsmanager` class correctly of `aws-sdk`.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
import SM from 'aws-sdk/clients/secretsmanager';
const secretManagerClient = new SM();

export const randomMethod = async () => {
  const personalToken = {
    SecretId: process.env.secretId || '',
  };
  try {
    const data = await secretManagerClient.getSecretValue(personalToken).promise();
    return data.SecretString;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`[SECRETS MANAGER] Error fetching personal token : ${err}`);
  }
};
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { randomMethod } from '.';
import SM from 'aws-sdk/clients/secretsmanager';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import { PromiseResult } from 'aws-sdk/lib/request';

jest.mock('aws-sdk/clients/secretsmanager', () => {
  const mSecretManagerClient = {
    getSecretValue: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    promise: jest.fn(),
  };
  return jest.fn(() => mSecretManagerClient);
});

describe('69977310', () => {
  test('should get secret value', async () => {
    process.env.secretId = 's1';
    const mSecretManagerClient = mocked<InstanceType<typeof SM>>(new SM());
    const mGetSecretValueRequest = mocked(mSecretManagerClient.getSecretValue());

    mGetSecretValueRequest.promise.mockResolvedValue({
      SecretString: JSON.stringify({ password: '123456' }),
    } as PromiseResult<any, any>);
    const actual = await randomMethod();
    expect(actual).toEqual(JSON.stringify({ password: '123456' }));
    expect(mSecretManagerClient.getSecretValue as jest.Mocked<any>).toBeCalledWith({ SecretId: 's1' });
  });

  test('should throw error', async () => {
    process.env.secretId = 's1';
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation(() => 'suppress error log for testing');
    const mSecretManagerClient = mocked<InstanceType<typeof SM>>(new SM());
    const mGetSecretValueRequest = mocked(mSecretManagerClient.getSecretValue());

    const mError = new Error('network');
    mGetSecretValueRequest.promise.mockRejectedValue(mError);
    await randomMethod();
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith(`[SECRETS MANAGER] Error fetching personal token : ${mError}`);
    expect(mSecretManagerClient.getSecretValue as jest.Mocked<any>).toBeCalledWith({ SecretId: 's1' });
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/69977310/index.test.ts (7.722 s)
  69977310
    ✓ should get secret value (4 ms)
    ✓ should throw error (1 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 6                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.282 s, estimated 10 s
```

package versions:

```json
"aws-sdk": "^2.875.0",
"typescript": "^4.1.2",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and you're right, I misread the AWS SDK documentation. However, I'm struggling to make this work. For more context, I'm currently unit testing a lambda that uses the `randomMethod()`, and I'm trying to link that method to this mocked SecretsManager instance, and despite not having the config error anymore, the `getSecretValue()`  isn't returning the secret I want. I've updated the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I've overlooked the fact that I was using a callback in order to bypass the `promise()`.

The following is the correct code:

```
const mockGetSecretValue = jest.fn((SecretId, callback) => {
  console.log("secretId", SecretId)
  switch (SecretId) {
    case process.env.GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN:
      const data = {
        SecretString: process.env.GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN_VALUE,
      }
      callback(null, data)
      break;
    default:
      const err = new Error("secret not found")
      throw err
  }
})

jest.mock("aws-sdk/clients/secretsmanager", () => {
  return jest.fn(() => {
    return {
      promise: jest.fn(),
      getSecretValue: jest.fn(({ SecretId }, callback) => {
        return mockGetSecretValue(SecretId, callback)
      }),
    }
  })
})
```

Thanks again for your help @slideshowp2!